# How to create and modify a table data in Android

Tags: android, sql, xml, database, excel

I have a little problem and I don't know how to solve it! I hope you can help me. I have a database in SQL Server, I want to retrieve the data from a SQL Server table but I want to display them in a table created in android and then modify the rows and save it in the SQL Server table. I want to know, what control can I use to modify the data? I want something like a worksheet in excel. It is possible in Android?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.

If you want to retrieve data from an SQL server you also have to come up with a way to serve it to the Android app [protocol], implement the networking part on both ends, parse the data, display it using android UI components [ListView is the first one to look at] allow user to modify it and then send the data back to the server -- which, in turn, should be ready to write it back into the db.

There is no component in Android to do all this out of the box.

But, maybe, you're just looking for this? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.quickDB